# Impossible to keep android service private and declare it in manifest?

Tags: android, android-service, android-manifest, android-library

I am creating a closed source android library that will be used by other developers. Because it's closed source I'm being careful about what methods and classes I expose to the 3rd party.

So far I have gotten by making all classes package-private that I don't want the 3rd party to access directly.

I am running into problems with a service that is part of my library.  If I don't make my service package-private then I expose all of the public override methods from my service to the 3rd party, I want to avoid that. If I make the service package-private then the 3rd party is unable to declare the service in their manifest and thus the service won't run.

Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: Hello Noen, To run Service, you must declare someware either in library's manifast file or application's manifast file. Without declaring Service cannot be started. I think you should create ".or" file in which you can declare permission and library can be private

Comment: @KPBird I can't seem to find any information on a ".or" file. Can you point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: may i know what was your solution to this problem?